# How to Create a Coupon box with toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a coupon code showing button like this one. When the user slides to the left, the coupon code needs to show. Any ideas? Thank you.

[image: Coupon Code Button Image]

Comment: Plz, include your code.

Answer (score 2):

In the example below, I coded for 4 different scenarios.

I hope your problem will be solved this way. If you have any questions, write without hesitation.

### Run Code Snippet:

```js
var el;

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  el = event.target.closest('.coupon.onclick');
  el && el.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.coupon {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.coupon .code {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed green;
  color: green;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  user-select: all;
}

.coupon .mask {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  transition: .3s;
  user-select: none;
}

.coupon.onhover:hover .mask,
.coupon.onclick.active .mask {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.coupon.onhover:hover .mask.bottom,
.coupon.onclick.active .mask.bottom {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<h3>On Hover: Left Transform:</h3>

<div class="coupon onhover">
  <div class="code">0AB9XOIJ</div>
  <div class="mask">Coupon Code</div>
</div>

<h3>On Hover: Bottom Transform</h3>

<div class="coupon onhover">
  <div class="code">0AB9XOIJ</div>
  <div class="mask bottom">Coupon Code</div>
</div>

<h3>On Click: Left Transform</h3>

<div class="coupon onclick">
  <div class="code">0AB9XOIJ</div>
  <div class="mask">Coupon Code</div>
</div>

<h3>On Click: Bottom Transform</h3>

<div class="coupon onclick">
  <div class="code">0AB9XOIJ</div>
  <div class="mask bottom">Coupon Code</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is useful.